# Dynamic bill generation

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I have generated a bill there  are a number of items in the bill and I have to hide the items which have charge amt is = 0 and it should print the item on the bill which has charge `amt > 0`

this is my html  file

this my view bill page

1. List item

   ```
   <ion-title align="left">Bill</ion-title>   </ion-navbar>
   ```

   English
           German
          Spanish
          French 
          Marathi

   -->

   #### **चारकोप (1)`enter code here`**
                  {{item.Society_Name}}</b> -->

   -->

   ```
   <div class="row" style=" border-bottom: solid black;
   border-width: 1px;">

     <div class="col">पावती क्रमांक :
       <b>{{this.name.bill_no}}</b>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div  style="display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto;">
       <div  style="  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       float:left;
       text-align: center;">Name :
       <b>{{this.name.bill_name}} </b></div>
       <div  style=" border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       float:right;
       text-align: center;">Bill Date :
       <b>{{this.name.bill_period}}</b></div>

       <div  style="  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       float:left;
       text-align: center;">
           Bill For : <b>{{this.name.bill_period}}</b>
       </div>
       <div  style=" border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       float:right;
       text-align: center;">
       Due Date : <b>{{this.name.bill_due}}</b>
       </div>

       <div  style="  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       float:left;
       text-align: center;">
          Wing :
          <b>{{this.name.wing}}</b>
       </div>
       <div  style=" border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
       float:right;
       text-align: center;">
          Floor No :  <b>2</b>
       </div>
   </div>
   <div  style="display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;">
         <div class="col" style="background-color: rgb(255, 173, 22);
         color: white;  float: left; " >
           <b>Sr.</b>
         </div>
         <div class="col" style="background-color: rgb(255, 173, 22);
         color: white;  float: left;  " >
           <b>शुल्क विशेष</b>
         </div>
         <div class="col" style="background-color: rgb(255, 173, 22);
         color: white;  float: left; ">
           <b>रक्कम</b>
         </div>
   </div>
   <div  style="display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;">

         <div class="col" style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" >
           <div class="row" style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" *ngFor="let item of particulars; let i = index">{{i + 1}}</div>
         </div>
         <div class="col"  size="8" style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227); " >

         <div class="row"   style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" *ngFor="let item of particulars">{{item.title}}</div>
         <!-- <ion-item *ngIf="this.products === charg_amt && charg_amt === 0"></ion-item> -->
         </div>
         <div class="col"  style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227); "  >
           <div class="row"   style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" *ngFor="let item of particulars">{{item.charg_amt}}</div>
           <!-- <ion-item *ngIf="!this.item.charg_amt.deleted === false">{{name.charg_amt}} </ion-item> -->
           <!-- <div *ngIf="this.products === charg_amt">  -->

         </div>

   </div>
   <!-- <div class="row" style=" border-bottom: solid black;
   border-width: 1px;">
     <div class="col particularsList" style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" col-2>
       <div class="row particularsList" style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" *ngFor="let item of particulars; let i = index">{{i + 1}}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col particularsList"  style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);"  col-50>
       <div class="row particularsList"   style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" *ngFor="let item of particulars">{{item.charge_title}}</div>
     </div>
     <div class="col particularsList"  style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);"  col-3>
       <div class="row particularsList"   style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" *ngFor="let item of particulars">{{item. charge_amt}}</div>
     </div>
   </div> -->

   <div  style="display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto;
   grid-gap: 1px; border-bottom: solid black;
   border-width: 1px;">
     <div class="col" style="grid-column: 1 / span 2;">मागील तारख :- २१७०८</div>
     <div class="col" >
       <div class="row" style="grid-column: 2 ;">
         <div class="col">उप एकूण ₹</div>

         <div class="col">{{this.name.sub_Total}}</div>
       </div>
       <div class="row" style=" border-bottom: solid black;
       border-width: 1px;">
         <div class="col particularsList"  style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" >
           <b>एकूण देय रक्कम ₹</b>
         </div>
         <div class="col particularsList"  style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" >
           <b>{{this.name.grand_total}}</b>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row" style=" border-bottom: solid black;
   border-width: 1px;">
     <div class="col">
       <B>नियम:</B> 
         <P>1. प्रत्येक महिन्याच्या २० तारखेपर्यंत देखभाल खर्चाचा कर
         प्रदान करावा . कर प्रदान न केल्यास २१% दराने बाकी रक्कमेवर व्याज आकारला जाईल. </P>
       <P>2. प्रत्येक महिन्याच्या २० तारखेच्या आत देयकाची रक्कम प्रधान करावी.</P>
       <P>3. धनादेशाने रक्कम भरायची असल्यास धनादेश चारकोप  (१) 
         लि या नावाने.२० तारीखेयपूर्वी घ्यावा.</P> 
         <!-- <p *ngFor="let item of RuleData; let i = index">{{i+1}}.{{item.rule | translate }} </p>  -->

     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row" style=" border-bottom: solid black;
   border-width: 1px;">
     <div class="col particularsList"   style="background-color: rgb(228, 227, 227);" align="right">
       `enter code here` (1) 
     </div>
   </div>

   <div class="row authSign"  style=" height: 100px;" >
     <div class="col" align="right">
       <b>अधिकृत सही</b>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```

   {{item.title}} ({{item.charg_amt}})
           
             Bearbeiten
             Löschen
           
         
             
       
         
           
           
           Print

Comment: what is the issue you are facing here?

Comment: i put a condition ngIf ="this.products == = charg_amt its not properly work i have to hide item and charge amt but its hide somthing else

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  <ion-item-sliding *ngIf="!item.deleted && item.charg_amt" #products>
```

The change I've made is added a condition **&& item.charg_amt** in your ngIf